# Can you search directly in the URL with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The problem is that when I try to copy a route directly I get this error:

> Cannot Get / home

But when I navigate with the menu items I usually render the views, I have tried several ways as `browserHistory` to achieve that effect but I do not succeed, I wonder, if `react-router-dom` does not allow navigation directly in the URL or is it an error in my code:

```js
// Dependencies

import React, { Component} from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, browserHistory, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

//components

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>App!</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/home"> Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about"> About </Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/contact"> Contact </Link></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <h2>Home Page!</h2>
        )
    } 
} 

class About extends Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <h2>About Page!</h2>   
        )
    }
}

class Contact extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <h2>Contact Page!</h2>
        )
    }
} 

// routes

render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
            <Route component={App} path="/" />
            <Route component={Home} path="/home" />
            <Route component={About} path="/about" />
            <Route component={Contact} path="/contact" />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jjn1r4zqny) but it seems to work. Can you try replicate there or try explain better what is not working?

Comment: there if it works for me but when I try it on my server not work, I&amp; I am  using webpack dev serv to create the server, is that ok?

Comment: I have solved it! for those who have the same error, I share what I did;    to see the problem if it was from the server so I had to configure webpack with "historyApiFallback: true" or put  "--historyApiCallback" in the script of webpack  dev server in the package.json luck :)

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! for those who have the same error, I share what I did;    to see the problem if it was from the server so I had to configure webpack with "historyApiFallback: true" or put  "--historyApiCallback" in the script of webpack  dev server in the package.json luck :)